# How can I force installation of Android app from Android Studio 4.1.3?

Tags: android, android-studio, reinstall

Android Studio "helpfully" skips installation and restarts what is on the phone

```
04/10 13:47:09: Launching 'app' on Physical Device.
App restart successful without requiring a re-install.
```

what is a lie (as app in not installed at all) and predictably fails immediately:

```
Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found
Error while Launching activity
```

How can I actually install my app?

Uninstalling app from phone failed to change anything.

Restarting Android Studio and dropping caches also failed.

The same for disconnecting and connecting phone.

Comment: can u share the manifest file ?

Comment: @ADITYARANADE https://github.com/matkoniecz/Zazolc/blob/fork/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: None of your activities is set as a "Launcher Activity" maybe thats causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Change `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />`
to `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`

This will solve the issue, as DEFAULT is not accepted in all versions of Emulators